# MVC - Rerender DropdownList on change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I'm new at MVC 4 and I have the following situation. I have a @Html.DropDownList where the Categories for a product are listed and right next to it I have another @Html.DropDownList which I'd like to populate with the subcategories of the chosen Category (once this category is chosen)

Which will be the most basic and easy way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will have to use JQuery for something like that...

Comment: Try this library http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/AjaxDropdownDemo/Index